# C# -Add parameters to query from Dictionary

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a problem which i don't know how to resolve it.
I want to be able to run the same query in the same operation and in that case i created a dictionary which hold the values which need to be added in the queries.

The query is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@{0}, @{1}, @{2});
```

As i said i have a Dictionary which contain all the data that i want to store in DB. Using a string builder i create the query which have values as the key in the dictionary. For example:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@1, @2, @3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@4, @5, @6);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@7, @8, @9);
```

Now when i want to change the key with the value the query is not modified.
This is what i am using in order to do that:

```
lCommand.Parameters.AddRange(lParameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter(string.Format("@"+x.Key.ToString()), x.Value)).ToArray());
```

Where lParameters is the dictionary.

Have a good one!

---

Edit:
Ok I will add the code which is create the string builder and the code which is executing the query.
Here I create the string builder which will contain all the insert queries.

```
int lCurrentIndex = 0;

        foreach (var litem in inCollection)
        {
            inSqlBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format(SQL.Insert, lPageCurrentIndex + 1, lPageCurrentIndex + 2, lPageCurrentIndex + 3));

            Guid TemplateIdentifier = new Guid();
            inDictionary.Add(lPageCurrentIndex + 1, ID);
            inDictionary.Add(lPageCurrentIndex + 2, Name);
            inDictionary.Add(lPageCurrentIndex + 3, Age);

            lPageCurrentIndex += 3;
        }
```

After the query is created I am coming to a method to do this:

```
using (var lCommand = lConnection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        lCommand.Transaction = lTransaction;
                        lCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                        lCommand.CommandText = SqlBuilder.ToString();

                          lCommand.Parameters.AddRange(lParameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter($"@x.Key", x.Value)).ToArray());
                        if(SqlBuilder.Length>0)
                        await lCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
```

Comment: Show us your dictionary.

Comment: @grmbl Dictionary is defined like this: var lParameters = new Dictionary<int, object>() and contain all the information that i need: key that are generated are: 1,2,3,4,5... and the values is in order: ID, Name, Age, ID, Name,Age. E.g. {1, 1}, {2, "Peter"}, {3, 22}, etc.

Comment: Is your table actually named **TestDB** or is this a typo? Also, with the current C# theres no need to use string.format, you can just do `$"@{x.Key}"` instead

Comment: Don't you see you're missing Age here...?

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have because what you're trying to do confuses me... How do you match the number of parameters for your query on the vertical selection of your dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code and it works fine, here's how I did it:

```
//Sample data
Dictionary<int, object> lParameters = new Dictionary<int, object>();
lParameters.Add(1, 1);
lParameters.Add(2, "Peter");
lParameters.Add(3, 22);
lParameters.Add(4, 2);
lParameters.Add(5, "John");
lParameters.Add(6, 24);
lParameters.Add(7, 3);
lParameters.Add(8, "Glenn");
lParameters.Add(9, 33);


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Your connection string"))
{
    conn.Open();  
    using (SqlCommand lCommand = new SqlCommand("query", conn))
    {
        lCommand.Parameters.AddRange(
            lParameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter($"@{x.Key}", x.Value)).ToArray());

        for (int i = 1; i <= lParameters.Count; i+=3)
        {
            lCommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO[dbo].[TestDB]([ID], [Name], [Age]) 
                                     VALUES(@{i}, @{i + 1}, @{i + 2});";      
            lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

So, you mean without using parameters but retrieving the dictionary value for each index?

```
using (SqlCommand lCommand = new SqlCommand("query", conn))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lParameters.Count; i += 3)
    {
        lCommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO[dbo].[TestDB]([ID], [Name], [Age])
                VALUES({lParameters[i]}, '{lParameters[i + 1]}', {lParameters[i + 2]});";
        lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

OR using a stringbuilder to load multiple queries into a single string and then execute it:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= lParameters.Count; i += 3)
        query.Append($"INSERT INTO[dbo].[TestDB]([ID], [Name], [Age])
                    VALUES({lParameters[i]}, '{lParameters[i + 1]}', {lParameters[i + 2]});");

    using (SqlCommand lCommand = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), conn))
        lCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> Just remember to place single quotes if the field is a string

Comment: I understand. But i am looking to create the command Text to look like this: 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@1, @2, @3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@4, @5, @6);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDB] ([ID], [Name], [Age]) VALUES (@7, @8, @9);
Where @1,@2,@3 to be the values from the dictionary from the given key. For example for key=1 to give me the ID which is in the dictionary(e.g. 1) and for the key =2 to give me the name from the dictionary which is Peter for example

Comment: something like that, but ExecuteNonQuery Command to be don once the the CommandTest is complete with all the inserts in that Table.

Comment: @AlexandruFlorin yes, that's what I do in my last code sample. So did you figure out what your problem is?

Comment: Yes. Thank you a lot. Now I am testing to see if everything is in order.